# Which file-path to use with localhost after moving site from static environment

Tags: html, iis, path, relative-path, file-location

I have a static website that is locally stored in the C drive: **C:\site**

I've now created a new site within IIS and pointed it to that location.
When I type '**localhost**' in the browser, it pulls up the sites index.html

The issue is I've lost all CSS / JS / etc. and I assume this is because my paths aren't pointing to the right source. I have the same issue for links (hrefs).

Before connecting to IIS, my paths were as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:/Site/css/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:/Site/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:/Site/css/style.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Site/scripts/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Site/scripts/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

I've tried looking around for answers, as well as trying some things such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="localhost/Site/css/style.css" />
```

OR:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/Site/css/style.css" />
```

But still no luck in seeing my CSS, JS, etc.

As for the links, they were working before IIS and looked like this:

```
<a href="/Site/about.html">About Us</a>
```

I assume once I can achieve the correct paths for my CSS & JS I'll be able to figure out the links. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your folder structure is this:

```
css
  style.css
index.html
```

Then the path `css/style.css` will always work from `index.html`, regardless of where it's hosted.  You're hard-coding root paths in the references, so when the root path changes in any way it's going to break all the references.

Try:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
```

(With the same change applied to other references.)

You can always reference files relative to *each other*, but referencing them relative to the *root* requires a consistent root.

Comment: Worked like a charm, and makes perfect sense now! Thank you very much!